# Manually transferring USMT2.UNC to fresh install.  File and Settings Transfer Wizard doesn't work.

Tags: windows, file-transfer, data-transfer

`USMT2.UNC` is an image file that the File and Settings Tranfer Wizard creates.

I copied the image to an external HDD.  When I tried to drag the file (which is half the size of the internal HDD) to my desktop, the internal HDD filled up.

Now, somehow, some of the files are on my computer, and the image files are taking up space too. It's almost as if some redundancy is ocurring.

I'm not sure my two versions of FAST are identical. I know they are supposed to be, I just don't know how to check.

I would be willing to use some third party software to do this. I have a perfectly intact USMT2.UNC file on the external.  Any suggestions?